# If $p(x)=a_0+a_{1}x+a_2(1+x^2), \text{calculate }L^{n}(p(x)).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L be the operator on $P_3$ defined by

$L(p(x)=xp'(x)+p''(x)$

If $p(x)=a_0+a_{1}x+a_2(1+x^2), \text{calculate }L^{n}(p(x)).$

$p(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2) \\ p'(x)=a_1+a_2(2x) \\p''(x)=2a_2 \\ L(p(x))=xp{'}(x)+p''(x)=a_1x+2a_2(1+x^2)  \\ L^2(p(x))= L(L(P(x))=L(a_1x+2a_2(1+x^2))$

How does one derive the meaning of $L^{2}$. How how does one find $L^{n}$.

Comment: @flytothesurface $(x \cdot p'(x))'=p'(x)+xp''(x) \neq x\cdot p'(x)+p''(x).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be induction. For $n=1$ we have 
$$\operatorname L(a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2))=a_1x+2a_2(1+x^2).$$
Assume we have
$$\operatorname L^n(a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2))=a_1x+2^{n}a_2(1+x^2)$$ for a number $n\in \mathbf N$, then
$$ \operatorname L^{n+1}(a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2)) = \operatorname L(\operatorname L^n(a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2)) \stackrel{\text{IH}}{=} \operatorname L(a_1x+2^{n}a_2(1+x^2)) =a_1x+2^{n+1}a_2(1+x^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $L$ is a linear operator of $\mathbf P_3.$ Observe also that
$$
L(1)=0, L(x)=x, \text{ and } L(1+x^2)=2(1+x^2),
$$
that is, $L$ is diagonalizable in a basis $(1,x,1+x^2).$ It follows that
$$
L^n(1)=0, L^n(x)=x, \text{ and } L^n(1+x^2)=2^n (1+x^2)
$$
for all $n \ge 1.$ Therefore
$$
L^n( a_0 +a_1x+a_2 (1+x^2))=a_1 x + 2^n a_2 (1+x^2)=2^n a_2x^2 +a_1 x+2^n a_2.
$$
for all $n \ge 1.$

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the simplest way is to obtain the matrix $M$ of $L$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,1+x^2\}$

Here is how.

- $L(1)=0=0+0x+0(1+x^2)$, thus associated with coefficients $(0,0,0)$ for the first column of $M$.
- $L(x)=x=0+1x+0(1+x^2)$, thus associated with coefficients $(0,1,0)$ for the second column of $M$.
- $L((1+x^2)=2(1+x^2)=0+0x+2(1+x^2)$, thus associated with coefficients $(0,0,2)$ for the third column of $M$.

Thus

$$\tag{1}M=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2} \ \ \iff \ \ \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2}\pmatrix{a_0\\a_1\\a_2}=\pmatrix{0\\a_1\\2a_2}$$

Remark: the second form of (1) could have been obtained directly.

As a consequence of (1), $$M^n=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2^n} \ \ \iff \ \ \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2^n}\pmatrix{a_0\\a_1\\a_2}=\pmatrix{0\\a_1\\2^na_2}$$

which is equivalent to say that:

$$L^n(a_0+a_1x+a_2(1+x^2))=a_1x+2^{n}a_2(1+x^2)$$